# Automatically adding commit comments in SVN directly from code in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive

So I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm hoping it is. Basically, we just moved to SVN from Sourcesafe (I know a lot of you almost threw up in your mouth just now ;)) and I'm setting up eclipse to work with it. I installed Subversive and have a repo set up with my project. Just FYI, I'm working on an Android project written in Java. Here's what I want:

As I'm working on each Java file making changes, I want to write the SVN Commit Messages right their in code just as I add javadoc comments. This is because I have to change a ton of files before I commit and I want to remember each thing I changed (client requirement). But I don't want to have to remember all of that (especially as I'm deleting a lot of code) and them add the comments when I commit all my changes from all my files. Ideally, I simply add some tag and then the commit message that SVN understands and as I commit the file, I don't have to manually add the comments but it gets done automatically based on the commit messages tagged in my source file?

As an example, say I deleted a function foo in footest.java, I would simply type in the following in footest.java:

// *_*_ (hopefully some tag here) deleted foo

Now when footest.java is commmitted, I don't have to type anything, the commit message 'deleted foo' gets added to it.

Finally, ideally, this is done automatically per revision. That is, once I make another change in footest.java, say, added function newfoo(), I could tag it like before with comment "added newfoo()" and when I commit only "added newfoo" comment gets put on the revision and not the one for the previous version "deleted foo".

Is this possible? Any issue anyone sees here?

Thanks,
-Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, mixing your commit messages & your code is discouraged.

Subversion (or any client I'm aware of) has nothing of the kind built in, because it would require knowledge of the code itself and your custom markup.

You would need to write a wrapper around `svn commit` (or your client's equivalent) to process your files.

But have you considered that to do this *right*, you'd also have to remove those comments from your code once you've committed the changes? Now you're into your wrapper script messing with your code - and a bug there could break your code, either introducing subtle, hard-to-find bugs or rendering it impossible to compile.

Why not just keep a text file on your desktop with your notes? Or make smaller self-contained commits instead of delaying until the point where you've forgotten why you made some of the changes?